getting weird sql error: ERROR: invalid input syntax for type double precision: "promo_email_click"-- related to nested subqueries?
I keep getting an error in this query when I try to count the distinct item_ids that I'm pulling from a subquery.
Everything works fine with the query until I try specifically to only count unique items from the subquery. In other words, the subqueries are all working fine, it's only with the final, outermost query where the issue arises.
I keep getting an error:

ERROR: invalid input syntax for type double precision: "promo_email_click"

which makes no sense to me. There's no double precision datatype in the query at all, nor is there anything called 'promo_email_click', so I'm pretty confused. Please help!
enter image description here
SELECT 
    COUNT(distinct test_) AS unique_item_ids_in_window
FROM
    (SELECT
         -- only pull item_ids
         int_item_id AS test_
     FROM
         (SELECT
              -- create a binary label for the events, where each event is either in the 30 days after test started window (1) or not (0)
              int_item_id,
              time_of_item_view,
              (CASE 
                   WHEN time_of_item_view > '2015-03-14 00:00:00' 
                        AND time_of_item_view < '2015-04-13 00:00:00' 
                       THEN CAST('1' as INT)
                       ELSE CAST('0' AS INT)
               END) AS In_30_day_window
          FROM
              -- for the view_item events, turn the 'parameter value' from a string  to a float
              (SELECT 
                   CAST (parameter_value AS FLOAT) AS int_item_id,
                   event_time AS time_of_item_view
               FROM 
                   -- select only view_item events
                   (SELECT *
                    FROM dsv1069.events 
                    WHERE events.event_name = 'view_item') AS only_view_items
           ) AS parameter_value_turned_to_float   
       ) AS only_in_30_day_window
WHERE 
    only_in_30_day_window.In_30_day_window = 1) AS ONLY_in_30_day_window_yes
GROUP BY 
    ONLY_in_30_day_window_yes.test_
        -- tried ordering by test_ but keep getting an error

Tried an aggregate function on a subquery and keep getting the error

org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: invalid input syntax for type double precision: "promo_email_click"


Check: CAST (parameter_value AS FLOAT)  because this throws the error you have: select cast('error' as float)   Or, in other words, one of the values for parameter_value  is "promo_email_click", which cannot be casted to a float.

Oh god, you were right! Thanks so much!!!!
